# How to find out ip address of router

Tags: macos, ip-address

How can I find out what IP my router on my local area network is using?

Comment: What Operating system?

Comment: my os is mac os x

Answer (score 11):

**Update:**

In Terminal.app type

```
route get default
```

or

```
route get default | grep gateway
```

for more condensed output.

This is the fastest way as pointed out by Daniel. Thanks Dan.

**Original Anwser:**

There is another way that will take a lot longer:

```
netstat -r | grep default
```

---

The convention is to give the router the first address on the subnet. This means, in most cases, your router's IP address is the same as your IP address except it ends in 1.

For example:

If your IP is 10.0.0.105, then your router's IP is probably 10.0.0.1.
If your IP is 192.168.1.83, then your router's IP is probably 192.168.1.1

Comment: It should be noted that the router also often is assigned the last IP address in the subnet. For example 192.168.1.254 or 10.0.0.254. For home router's default configurations Jay's addresses are far more likely though.

Comment: What's the difference between this and the faster `route get default`?

Comment: Also keep in mind that if the LAN you're on has internal DNS that the router's IP may not be shown, but its' hostname. Which you can just give to the `host` command to get the IP.

Comment: @Daniel Beck, The difference is that netstat takes a lot longer :) I updated my answer. +1 for being awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I was at first a bit confused by the output from the `route get default | grep gateway` commands on my Mac (OS X 10.9.4), as it yielded in my case a host name rather than an IP address.

```
gateway: homeportal
```

In case anyone else comes here wanting the IP address as well, adding the `-n` option could possibly help (according to the documentation, it will *bypass attempts to print host and network names symbolically when reporting actions*):

```
route -n get default | grep gateway
```

which yielded:

```
gateway: 192.168.1.254
```

Comment: This is the best answer for macOS.  You can also a pipe it through awk to strip the extra text.

`route -n get default | grep gateway | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the local address of the router it's most likely your gateway address. Press the Apple Menu () , got to 'System Preferences', then go to 'Network'. Select any of the items on the left (Ethernet/AirPort) that say connected.

On the right will be a bunch of fields, one of which is 'Router', which is usually 192.168.1.1.

If you want your internet IP address you can just go to http://www.whatsmyip.net/ and it will show you there.

Comment: you'll have to go into advanced, and click on the TCP/IP tab for the more specific information